# Get data from object where value name has a space

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, I can get this to return the right city with my data:

```
console.log(selected_things[0].City);
```

However, I need to actually get the zip code, but this doesn't work.

```
console.log(selected_things[0].Zip Code);
```

How do you handle this where the value name has a space in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the square bracket notation again with a string literal

```
console.log(selected_things[0]["Zip Code"]);
```

All properties of an object can be accessed by the dot notation followed by the name or the square bracket notation with a string as the indexer.

The caveat is when the attribute name is an invalid identifier and therefore must be accessed with square bracket notation.

Comment: I knew there had to be a way to do this, but couldn't figure it out. This worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @jonmrich I'm glad this makes sense now :D

Comment: I always appreciate it when someone adds a little explanation to an answer too. Thanks.